# Table tag malforming in aspx master page

Tags: asp.net, html

I am having a problem with a nested table on my master page, it has been working up until the latest addition I added to one of the nested pages.

In this table i have a asp:contentplaceholder in the body that I use to fill in for the rest of the pages

The table on the master page looks like:

```
<table class="headermaintable" frame="vSides">
<tr>
<td class="headermaintd">
<table id="MasterTableID" style="height:100%;" class="widewidth" cellpadding="7">
    <tr class="headertop"> 
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>  
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="2" style="border-left:2px solid #000000;">
            <a class="BlueLink" href="..." target="_blank">
            <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server' ImageUrl="~/images/image2.gif" />
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and what I have found that it is doing, is it is taking the last table row from the nested table and putting into the main table like this:

```
...
        <td>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="2" style="border-left:2px solid #000000;">
            <a class="BlueLink" href="..." target="_blank">
            <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server' ImageUrl="~/images/image2.gif" />
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have looked over the html in the other page and all tags are properly opened and closed. Has anyone seen anything similar to this? If you need an example from the nested page its having problems with I can add something.

Thanks to all that can offer helpful advice

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlPriceDisc" runat="server" Visible="false">
  <asp:DataList ID="dlQtyBreak" RepeatLayout="Table" Runat="Server" width="85%" CellPadding="1" CellSpacing="1">
      <HeaderTemplate>
   <tr class="style4" bgcolor="#dedede">
      <td colspan="5" align="center">
        <b>Current Price Breaks</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#dedede" class="style4">
           <td align="center" width="20%"><b>Low</b></td>
      <td align="center" width="20%"><b>High</b></td>
      <td align="center" width="20%"><b>Price</b></td>
           <td align="center" width="20%"><b>Sale Price</b></td>
      <td align="center" width="20%"><b>Delete</b></td>
    </tr>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr class="style5" bgcolor="#eeeeee">
      <td align="center" valign="middle" width="20%">
        <asp:TextBox id="txtPBLowQty" ... />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ... />
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ... />
      </td>
           <td align="center" valign="middle" width="20%">
        <asp:TextBox id="txtPBHighQty"... />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ... />
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ... />
      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" width="20%">
        <asp:TextBox id="txtPBPrice"  ../ />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ... />
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ... />
      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" width="20%">
        <asp:TextBox id="txtPBSalesPrice" ... />
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ... />
      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" width="20%">
        <asp:Button id="btnPBDelete" ... />
        <asp:Label id="lblPBLinenum" ... />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
     <table width="85%" id="PBRowAdd" runat="server" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" visible="false">
  <tr bgcolor="#eeeeee" class="style5">
         <td align="center" valign="middle" width="20%">
      <asp:TextBox id="txtPBLowQtyAdd" ... />
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ... />
      <asp:RegularExpressionValidator .../>
    </td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" width="20%">
      <asp:TextBox id="txtPBHighQtyAdd" ... />
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ... />
      <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ... />
    </td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" width="20%">
      <asp:TextBox id="txtPBPriceAdd" ... />
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ... />
      <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ... />
    </td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" width="20%">
      <asp:TextBox id="txtPBSalesPriceAdd" ... />
      <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ... />
    </td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" width="20%">
      <asp:Button id="btnPBAddNew" ... />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
     <br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <asp:Button ID="btnPBRowAdd" .../>
      <asp:button id="btnPBBack" ... />
      <asp:button id="btnPBUpdateQtyBreakList" ... />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
   </asp:Panel>
```

Now in this example is the only one I have found where it causes the issue, and if I hide table "PBRowAdd" the issue goes away, but as soon as I make the table visible it causes the problem. What is it doing to cause it?

Again thanks to anyone who can offer help on the issue.

Comment: Out of subject, but using table for layout is widely discouraged by the modern web standards...

Comment: Are those other pages using the same master page? If they are, then it isn't an error in the master page, which most likely is. Your error is probably inside the content of the page.

Comment: @Dan yes, this is the only master page used and all other pages use this page. What ever is causing it causes it on the master page only though. I can post the specific potion of the nested page where I see there error. I will edit in. Thank you

Comment: Is this what's being rendered, with the ContentPlaceholder not being replaced by anything?  And are you using any Javascript?

Comment: There is no javascript, and the contentPlaceholder is always being replaced. the error is contained on one page and in one panel now listed in the question. Thanks

Comment: I notice your DataList has table content but no table tags.  Are you counting on the DataList itself to generate the <table> and </table>?  Because I'd have to test this, but I believe if it generates those it also generates <tr> and <td> tags around each data list item.  That will cause problems since your template content is all table rows.  You might want to try a Repeater control instead.

Comment: @AnnL. I did not think of that. I did just try the suggestion, but it still causes the same problem. Thanks for that tip though.

Comment: @SteveNicks  OK, I'm going to assume that you now have table tags in or around your DataList or are using a Repeater with table tags in the markup.  If you take the generated output from your page and load it into a web page in VS, does it point out any markup errors?

Comment: @AnnL. I did end up replacing the DataList with a Repeater and it does have the table tags within the control. I am unsure what you are asking in the second part of your last tip when you say load it into a web page in visual studio.

Comment: Yeah, that's a bit unclear.  I meant:  display the page, view the HTML source, and select, copy, and paste the entire page's HTML into a new HTML file in VS.  (I think you can do this without saving the HTML file).  Does VS's intellisense flag any errors in the HTML?

Comment: Ahh did the only error to arrise was 'Element Table cannot be nested within element tr' .. so I took care of that and I am still seeing the same thing happen. Thanks for recommending that